# Empty tableview without a crash while everything is connected well

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I get empty tableview after making everything right while ,Datasource , delegate are connected to the view-controller and The cell Id are the same and I didn't get any crash the app runs but it show a empty tableview!

```
import UIKit

class Feed: SLKTextViewController {

    var data = ["data"]

    @IBOutlet var tv: UITableView!
//    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
//        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
//    }

//    override class func tableViewStyleForCoder(decoder: NSCoder) -> UITableViewStyle {
//        return UITableViewStyle.Plain;
//    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//        self.tv.registerClass(FeedCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.bounces = true
        self.shakeToClearEnabled = true
        self.keyboardPanningEnabled = true
        self.inverted = false

        self.textView.placeholder = "Message"
        self.textView.placeholderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

        self.leftButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "icn_upload"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.leftButton.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        self.rightButton.setTitle("Send", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        self.textInputbar.autoHideRightButton = true
        self.textInputbar.maxCharCount = 140
        self.textInputbar.counterStyle = SLKCounterStyle.Split
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return data.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedCell

    // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]

    return cell

    }



    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

TableviewCell

```
import UIKit


class FeedCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet var time: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var userImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var username: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var Textcontent: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var likeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var commentsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var img: UIImageView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

```
2015-08-19 02:35:24.928[75798:5132607] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:heightCanBeGuessed:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.4/UITableViewRowData.m:1849
2015-08-19 02:35:24.937[75798:5132607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac739b5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010caa4deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ac7381a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010b2eab72 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010b9f5f3b -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 353
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010b7f2d55 -[UITableView _rectForRowAtIndexPath:canGuess:] + 152
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b801028 __53-[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 2736
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b763548 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 65
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b80055f -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:] + 475
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010b7f93d1 -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 437
    10                       0x000000010aa8da92 _TFC144Feed9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 210
    11                       0x000000010aa8dcaf _TToFC144Feed9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 79
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010b80b0c6 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 782
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b80b1db -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010b7e1250 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3187
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010b813fa8 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010b7fc599 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 218
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010b76da3b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000011077a36a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    19  QuartzCore                          0x000000011076ebd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010b75e3d8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1083
    21                       0x000000010aaa22b8 -[SLKTextViewController viewWillAppear:] + 296
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010b84c7b6 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 710
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010b84ce50 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 149
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010b75c4b5 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 633
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010b769e0e -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 475
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010b726a62 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 803
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010b726e79 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 302
    28  UIKit                               0x000000010b7386dc -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 43
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010b6b8d13 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4003
    30  UIKit                               0x000000010b6bf13d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1755
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010b6bc390 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    32  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f7c47ac -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f7c4b1a -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab9fb21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab95a4c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab94f03 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab94918 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    38  UIKit                               0x000000010b6bbd2d -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    39  UIKit                               0x000000010b6c099e UIApplicationMain + 171
    40                       0x000000010aa8f47d main + 109
    41  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d63192d start + 1
    42  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> 
> 
> 2015-08-19 02:47:12.242[76140:5147381] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3505.4/UITableView.m:6540
2015-08-19 02:47:12.249[76140:5147381] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072a59b5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001090dcdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072a581a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010791cb72 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 198
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000107e2c32f -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 275
    5                        0x00000001070c2ab8 _TFC144Feed9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 120
    6                        0x00000001070c2caf _TToFC14Feed9tableViewfS0_FTCSo11UITableView21cellForRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_CSo15UITableViewCell + 79
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000107e3e0c6 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 782
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000107e3e1db -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 74
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000107e14250 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 3187
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000107e46fa8 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] + 92
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000107e2f599 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 218
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000107da0a3b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cdbc36a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010cdb0bd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000107d913d8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 1083
    16                       0x00000001070d72b8 -[SLKTextViewController viewWillAppear:] + 296
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000107e7f7b6 -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 710
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000107e7fe50 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 149
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000107d8f4b5 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _willMoveToWindow:withAncestorView:] + 633
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000107d9ce0e -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 475
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000107d59a62 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 803
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000107d59e79 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 302
    23  UIKit                               0x0000000107d6b6dc -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 43
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000107cebd13 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4003
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000107cf213d -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1755
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000107cef390 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    27  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bdfe7ac -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 192
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010bdfeb1a -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071d1b21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071c7a4c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071c6f03 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001071c6918 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    33  UIKit                               0x0000000107ceed2d -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000107cf399e UIApplicationMain + 171
    35                       0x00000001070c447d main + 109
    36  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000109c6b92d start + 1
    37  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `return 5`.  Does it get called?  If it does, put a breakpoint on `return cell` and examine the cell.  If the first breakpoint doesn't get called, then you have a problem setting your datasource.

Comment: it crash only after I put breakpoint after return 5 and it works well if i put breakpoint after return cell

Comment: Do you have correctly set data source property for your table view? Because I don't see it in provided code.

Comment: yes, connected though the view controller in storyboard

Comment: And why is your table view IBOutlet named `tv` an then you call `self.tableView.registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: when I change to self.tv.registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier it crash

Comment: You have to register class only when cell is not part of your storyboard. So if you have the cell in storyboard as part of your table view, remove `registerClass` method call. Do not forget set reuse identifier in storyboard too.

Comment: You are referencing `self.tableView` but you also have the `tv` outlet. Why both? Does this view controller extend `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController`?

Comment: I did exactly what you told me removed registerClass and set ID both in storyboard + TVC still same crash

Comment: I change that after deny's answer but still crash

Comment: two difeerent crash reports ? which issue are you currently facing ?

Comment: it is the second one

Comment: @marrioa does that appera when you click on header view

Comment: NO it crash immediately